# Node.JS EXE Deleting executing file

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

I have an monitor.js file that I turned into an executable using nexe.

I want the monitor to have the ability to uninstall itself, which means delete it's own .exe file and his containing directory.

I tried : (monitorPath = monitor.exe file path, installPath = monitor.exe folder)

```
childProcess.exec("TIMEOUT 3 && del " + monitorPath + " && rmdir " + installPath);

setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit(0);
}, 2000);
```

EDIT: It should run on windows, so those are all windows commands

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the start command

```
var installPath = path.join(exePath, "..");
var monitorPath = path.join(installPath, "qqmonitor.exe");
var delCommand = 'start cmd /c "cd .. && TIMEOUT 1 && del "' + monitorPath + '" && rmdir "' + installPath + '" && exit"';

log("Uninstalling with command : '" + delCommand + "'");
childProcess.exec(delCommand, null);

setTimeout(function () {
  process.exit(0);
}, 500);
```